# ICollectionView Does not support changes to its sourcecollection

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application and I've recently wrapped a couple of ObservableCollections inside an ICollectionView so that I could implement Sorting and Filtering.

```
Private _EntriesSource As New BankEntry.Collection
Public ReadOnly Property Entries As ICollectionView = Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_EntriesSource)
```

The sorting and filtering work well, but since doing this it seems a lot less thread friendly and despite wrapping any thing that touches the collection inside a Dispatcher thread call or using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization I still get errors saying this collection does not support changes to its sourcecollection ...

Examples of the sort of things I'm trying to do are just MyCollection.Add(item) or MyCollection.Remove(item).

Am I going in the wrong direction by moving from ObservableCollections to ICollectionView?
Are there better ways to sort and filter ObservableCollections whilst maintaining the ability to add and remove items from the collection?

Comment: Why are you getting the view and losing the view source?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases sorting and grouping data is a function of the View (not CollectionView but the MVVM view),  as such the best way of doing this is to create your CollectionViewSource in XAML bind that to your observable collection and then bind your controls to the CollectionViewSource

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsBodies" Source="{Binding Bodies}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <ComponentModel:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource cvsBodies}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

you can also create a CollectionViewSource on the VM

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        CollectionView.Source = Items;
        CollectionView.Filter += CollectionView_Filter;
        //only required if you are initialising the collection with values
        CollectionView.View.Refresh();

    }

    private void CollectionView_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
         //filter logic
    }

    public CollectionViewSource CollectionView { get; } = new CollectionViewSource();
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,1000) );
}
```

Comment: For completeness if anyone else is looking I think the ComponentModel: will need the following declaration xmlns:ComponentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

Comment: Mike this is great - could you expand on the filtering. What is the purpose of the EventTrigger and Binding Path=Filter? What would the Filter property look like? I presume the CollectionViewSource_Filter would be a simple code behind boolean function.

Comment: The way CollectionViewSource filters is via a Filter Event, if the filter is purely View based then just using the EventHandler is all you need, however if you are using your ViewModel to filter then you need to Bind the Filter event to the Filter command this is what the EventTrigger  is doing, the way the filter works is simple enough every item in the list is fed 1 by one into the filter event and the Accepted event arg is set to true or false see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if its not clear use Either Filter= or EventTrigger binding not both

Comment: realised was an error in my filter binding the default InvokeCommandAction doesn't support passing event args,  so removed that from the example

Comment: I'm working in a MVVM world - does this mean the filter has to sit in the code behind or is there a clean XAML way of filtering in the viewmodel?

Comment: @user3117326 you can also create the View Source on the VM updated example to show that, there are also other implementations of InvokeCommandAction that do support EventArgs such as Prism's, though they have locked that one to UIElements only, you just have to find the right one or write your own

Comment: I see you're using a CollectionViewSource, whereas I was using ICollectionView. I've tried this but when I bind the ListBox ItemsSource to the CollectionView property (type CollectionViewSource) it isn't showing any items. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: if you are using A collectionViewSource in the VM then you have to bind to the View property as this is where data changes are being reflected ie CollectionView.View

Comment: Great - that all seems to be working and I can now add items into the collection via code without hitting the thread issue. Thanks for pushing me through this.